# Magento, Help with SQL Query to get full product URL's

Tags: php, mysql, magento

So, basically I am looking to interact with the database outside of Magento. Upon reviewing tables in the database, catalog_product_flat_1 seems to store the majority of the information I am looking to retrieve so this gets me just all about everything but the final step.

I am trying to understand the relations within the Magento DB and get all the full product URL's into my newly created table.

The purpose of this is for an SEO/PPC initiative where having a nice list of every product sku, name, brand, description and url directly to the product would make the work a breeze.

I have everything working just fine aside from the full product URL.

I have been doing a good amount of reading and it appears more people are using SQL injections within the normal Magento methods, but I am looking to do this with the database outside of the site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd save yourself a lot of headache by not querying the database directly and using the API - the classes and methods for getting the information you're looking for is built for you. Just something to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Running raw SQL commands against the Magento database is time-consuming, not upgrade-proof and, in some cases, dangerous.  Use the models made available to you in the Magento codebase to perform your queries.

You could achieve your sku, name, brand, description and url would be done with:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Varien_Profiler::enable();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
Mage::app();

$fhandle = fopen("dump.csv", "w");
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $data = array(
        $product->getSku(),
        $product->getName(),
        $product->getBrand(), // Or whatever your attribute name is..
        $product->getDescription(),
        $product->getUrlPath()  
    );

    fputcsv($fhandle, $data);
}

fclose($fhandle);
```

I don't follow your use of "SQL Injections".  They are [attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), not ways of programming.

Comment: Hi Nick, I should not have used the word injection, I meant using the direct queries within Magentos code, or the "Magento" way. Thanks for the assistance, testing this now ;)

Comment: @Nick, where can I find some documentation for the `addAttributeToSelect()` method? I'm interested in knowing how to select specific attributes/columns of a product using this method.